# Auto update adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel which is constantly having new rows added. I then have another sheet (lets call it results) which is referencing this table, and counting the values in each column.

Every time I add a new record/row to my table, the results sheet throws a bunch of errors in every cell that references the column. Because I'm using a fixed range in the formula to count the column, e.g. `=SUM(A1:A10)`, I then need to manually click each cell in results and select 'include adjacent cells' to get the count to reflect the new data. I have loads of cells in this table and I'm adding data daily so this is a very long winded way of doing things.

I'm looking for a way that I can automatically update these cells, either by using a macro, or adjusting the formula so that it will automatically increase the range of the SUM when I add new data.

The best solution I've had so far was to simply define the range to include the row below my last piece of data (i.e. if A10 is my last record, the formula would be `=SUM(A1:A11)`). This works, and auto increments the formula when a new cell is added. However, if I delete the record from the table for any reason, the formula reverts to only including the range containing data.

In other words, this solution works, but only until I have to delete a record. Is there any better solution that can detect which rows are populated, and auto include them in the formula?

Comment: Is very most simply converting your interval to a real table: using the correct reference `[field]` you have only the rows in body range

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX('Sheet1!'A:A,1):INDEX('Sheet1!'A:A,LOOKUP(2,1/('Sheet1!'A:A<>""),ROW('Sheet1!'A:A))))`

Using INDEX and ROW reference, deleting cells won't result in broken cell references. LOOKUP is used to calculate the last non-empty cell in column A. This will auto update.
Using SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM makes it an array formula and does not require older Excel versions to enter the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` (because of the LOOKUP function)

In Office 365 you could use: `=SUM(FILTER('Sheet1!'A:A,'Sheet1!'A:A<>""))`

Comment: thanks, this solution works, but I have one problem still. When I place the formula in the same sheet as the data, it works perfectly, but my results are in a different worksheet. If i try to change the references to column A to `'Sheet1'!A` to reference the correct sheet, it gives me a name error. Do you know how I can use the formula between worksheets like this?